# td background picture asp:Image possible?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a given asp.net site in which I change pictures as I need like `Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Bilder/B1.png";`

These pictures are in table cells as `asp.Image`.

Is it possible to use these `asp:Image` as my background for the cell? Something like `<td style="background-image:ID('Image1')` so that I can change the background as I need through the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the example below -

Front Page -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td width="178" rowspan="3" background="<%= s_ImageUrl%>"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind -

```
Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Public s_ImageUrl As String
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    s_ImageUrl = "/image/test.jpg"
End Sub
```

End Class

Now you can change the `s_ImageUrl` variable to change the image.

Comment: thanks but always get the error `The name 's_ImageUrl' does not exist in the current context`. my aspx looks like `<td style="background-image:url('<%=s_ImageUrl%>')">`