# Image URL not changing in aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I have got the following code snippet in my page

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="testButton" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="testImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/triangle.png" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="testButton" Text="Change Image" OnClick="testButton_Click" />
```

and have got the following in my code behind

```
protected void testButton_Click ( object sender , EventArgs e ) {
    testImage.ImageUrl = "";
}
```

When I click on the button, the image is vanished since its URL has been set to empty string in code behind - I understand that. But when I view the page source, I see the original image URL as initialized in the asp page where I badly need URL to be set to empty string.

Comment: what browser are you using? the view page source button is showing you a new copy of the source from the server most likely (not your current source)

Comment: @wal google chrome

Comment: use F12 to view the current source

Comment: A quite similar solution you can find in the below link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408742/td-background-picture-aspimage-possible/37410245#37410245

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the ImageUrl value of your asp image in your markup as below:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="testButton" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Image ID="testImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%#changeableImageUrl %>" />
</ContentTemplate>
```

Code Behind:

```
public string changeableImageUrl;
protected void Page_Load ( object sender , EventArgs e ) {
    changeableImageUrl= "~/triangle.png"; // initial image URL
    this.DataBind (); // since data have been bound in the page by data binding syntax
                      // <%#changeableImageUrl %>
}
protected void testButton_Click ( object sender , EventArgs e ) {
    changeableImageUrl= ""; // to set html-rendered src attribute of img element to ""
    this.DataBind(); //bind data to the page
}
```

changeableImageUrl must be declared public within the page. Now, you can change changeableImageUrl to change the image URL.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused because the browser does not reload all source of page but if you change parameter in ScriptManager, In IDE, (not runtime). If you set to false EnablePartialRendering = false; this may solve your problem and always have new html code.